# How do I convert a verb to adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I want to say "You need activate added user." but I don't know why I say it. I don't know any rule for which I can say *add**ed** user*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Past Participles are used as attributive: adjectives placed in front of a noun.

> The **stolen** baby was found by the police unharmed.

> Dean's **broken** arm was set in plaster by the doctor at the hospital.

> The **required** steps are clearly listed in the email I sent you.

In your case, you could say "You need to activate the added user." if you are talking of a user account previously added that needs to be activated.

Answer (score 1):

Most past participles can be used as adjectives. An *added user* is a user that is added or that has been added. So you can say "you need to activate the added user”. Note that you need to use the article *the* since you are refering to a specific user that has just been mentioned.

However I find this formulation awkward, although I can't articulate why. I prefer "the newly added user” (or more wordy alternatives such as "the user that you just added” or "the user [who was] added in step 3”).

Comment: I agree the unqualified ***added*** sounds somewhat clumsy/unnatural in OP's context. It's okay in "ad-speak" *(breakfast cereal "with no added sugar", skimmed milk "now with added calcium", etc.)*, but they're in the sense of "additional ingredient", not "inserted into database".